# Can we pass objects types to plyr or data.table functions?

Tags: r, list, data.table, plyr, igraph

I am trying to find the easiest way to analyse data from a simulation. My output "a" looks like this, and is of `typeof(a)="list"` from `class(a)="matrix"`:

```
> a
      Variable Trial Bgraph Afgraph Mlog  
 [1,] 0.2      1     List,9 List,9  List,4
 [2,] 0.2      2     List,9 List,9  List,4
 [3,] 0.2      3     List,9 List,9  List,4
 [4,] 0.3      1     List,9 List,9  List,4
 [5,] 0.3      2     List,9 List,9  List,4
 [6,] 0.3      3     List,9 List,9  List,4
```

where "a" is a list matrix,"Variable" is a value of variable, "Trial" is the trial no. for that value, "Bgraph" and "Afgraph" are graph objects. They are single graph objects `class(a[[1,4]])="igraph"`; R stores them as List of 9 items. Lastly "Mlog" is the master log containing 4 matrices of different dimensions. I'd like to passe these objects to different functions and find averages.

To keep things simple I've replaced my functions with simpler ones:

**Q.1** Using plyr, I want to get average edge-count of trials for each variable. My best attempt gives me the following which is the individual edge-count:

```
ldply(a[,4],function(inp){mean(ecount(inp))})
```

**Q.2** I've also attempted using data.table package's "by" but cannot keep lists as key to a data.table. If I keep "a" as an array, I loose the class of igraph object.

`require(igraph); graph<- erdos.renyi.game(10, .4, "gnp")` will create some igraph objects. `ecount(graph)` is the built-in function for counting edges.

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: wow, I don't think I've seen a `matrix` of `list`s before!  I'd be tempted to just work with `list`s, what's your reason for using a `matrix`?

Comment: @SamMason :) The correct answer is lack of/bad programming experience! I prefer arrays/dataframes over lists due to habit. Also in R, when a function returns multiple objects it can only be through a list.
However, if you know any multi-variate/multi-dimensional simulation examples, please share them with me. It may help me avoid this problem altogether.

Comment: It would be helpful to see how you're creating `a`, I don't understand what `a[[1,4]]` is at the moment, is it a set of 9 graphs or something else?

Comment: @SamMason, `class(a[[1,4]])="igraph`. Also edited it in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd pull the `Variable` (and maybe `Trial`s) out into a `data.frame` and use `aggregate` from there:

```
df <- data.frame(Variable=unlist(a[,1]), Trial=unlist(a[,2]))
df$Edges <- laply(a[,4],ecount)
aggregate(Edges ~ Variable, data=df, mean)
```

should do what you want—assuming I understand what you want!

(I think you'll need `unlist` because you've got your `matrix` of `list`s)

Comment: :) Works!! with a minor change. `laply(...)` instead of `ldply(...)`
Thanks a lot for helping. Have a great day!

`> df <- data.frame(Variable=unlist(a[,1]), Trial=unlist(a[,2]))
> df$Edges <- laply(a[,4],ecount)
> aggregate(Edges ~ Variable, data=df, mean)
  Variable    Edges
1      0.2 120.0000
2      0.3 182.3333
3      0.4 234.6667
4      0.5 297.3333`

Comment: What I can't understand is how a data.frame type inherits the list and an array type does not. But I'll have to read the R documentation for that. :)

Comment: sorry for the `laply` vs `ldply`, I don't use `plyr` and I'd use `lapply` here.  kept your code because I thought it would help you!  changed my answer now

Comment: what do you mean "data.frame type inherits the list"?

Comment: Oh, got it! Dataframe is a type of list, arrays aren't.
`> is.list(array(1:10));is.list(data.frame(1:10))
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE`

Comment: a dataframe is a list of columns and various constraints (i.e. they're the same length) on them.  an array is a vector (with elements of some given type) that is normally treated with "rectangular" indices via its dimensions.  hope that helps!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40653/discussion-between-sam-mason-and-user2217564)